# SDL rtf for debian?

Tags: debian

I’ve seen SDL image, SDL GFX, and SDL TTF libraries in the Debian package archive, but not SDL rtf. Does this exist? When I search "libsdl2" in the archive, it doesn't turn up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be packaged... If you'd like to request it, run

```
reportbug wnpp
```

then pick option 5 ("RFP") and fill in the requested information.